# Making REST requests and parsing REST response in C++?

Tags: c++, rest, amazon-simpledb

I'm currently working on a project written completely in C++ and running on ubuntu. My requirement is to make REST based calls to Amazon SimpleDB to store/retrieve data.

Even though i know C++, i'm not sure how to proceed. Need some insight from the community on how to proceed.

Thanks,

Nitin

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDB is XML over HTTP: if you want to roll it from scratch, use either neon or curl for the http library, and probably libxml2 for the XML parsing. One alternative is also http://www.28msec.com/open_source/libaws: that might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a networking library that understands http protocol. Then you make http request to the web service (with required data to store). I don't know what Amazon SimpleDB returns, assuming it's JSON, you need a JSON parser library. Parse that, and display or do something else as you need.

Answer (score 0):

The sad truth is you'd probably be much happier if you did your project in something like Java, Python or C#.

If you absolutely need to use C++, I get the strong impression vjson would probably be your best bet:

http://code.google.com/p/vjson/